# Quoting a fictional character from a Book

Tags: quotes

I am considering having my senior quote be "Where are the Snowdens of Yesteryear?" from *Catch-22*.  Should this quote be attributed to Joseph Heller, or Yossarian?  If I do attribute it to Yossarian, should I refer to him as 'Yossarian', 'Capt. John Yossarian', or something else?

Comment: You could always punt and say "... of yesteryear?" *Yossarian*, in Joseph Heller's *Catch-22*.

Comment: I'd go with bare 'Yossarian': Heller's dead, but ***Yossarian lives***.

Comment: Heller's trustees are more likely to sue you than Yossarian's.

Comment: What is a "senior quote" ?

Comment: @Joe, in US high a schools (at least), it is traditional to create an annual "yearbook" listing all the members of the graduating class (and, these days, all the lower classes as well). The listing will include a portrait each each senior, with a quote of his own choosing appearing alongside his name as a caption. The idea is to give yourself a lifetime of enjoyment by allowing you to crack open your yearbook, look up your quote, and cringe at how undeservedly pretentious you were.

Comment: Awesome !!  I get it, for the yearbook